# Web application run without browser as a programm

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I have made a website wich uses HTML, PHP, Javascript and Ajax and is working based on MySQL database. My question is if there is a way to make this whole website run as a program with no need to open browser. Like outlook or filezilla where both are programs involving servers and web but they need no browser.

I dont expect you to give me a step by step guide but only to tell me if this is possible.

Comment: "Using a server" does not mean "Rendering the UI in HTML" or even "Accessing data over HTTP". Outlook speaks Exchange and IMAP. Filezilla speaks FTP. Their interfaces are not implemented in HTML.

Comment: So if i wanted to make my website to speak FTP u mean i must NOT render its UI in HTML? And if yes which method should i use and and would i still be able to use php javascript and ajax in an  FTP application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a headless browser, like Zombie.js that will allow you to browse your app programatically without employing a graphical browser. It supports AJAX call and everything.

This is usually done for testing whether the web app works as expected.

Anyway, if you want your app to be used without a browser, best you can do is transforming it into a console app.

If you want the app to be used from both the web and console, or other environment, you can make it work RESTful, and develop 2 interface layers: web, console or whatever you need, all of them consuming the same services so the functionality will be the same.

Comment: To transform my web project in a console app as u mentioned what i ll need? Can u point me into a direction? Is Java as mentioned earlier my answer?

Comment: Please clarify what you need. Why do you need to run the app "as a program"? You need the whole app as a desktop app, or just perform certain tasks?

Comment: I need the whole app as a desktop app. Please kindly advice :)

Comment: The Java solution proposed could work. It would provide an executable program that would show the webpage. It's like having a browser that will only connect to your webapp. But you need to deploy the app in a web server so it will be accesible.

Answer (score 0):

Sure,

you can develop a java application which uses for example JavaFX on the presentationlayer and there you'll have a class called **WebView** within you can display your HTML pages.

But you need to run your PHP Application on a WebServer which renders the page on runtime / calltime and serves the data. On this server you also run your MySQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

You could try HTA (HTML Applications). Note that its a product of Microsoft and I have tried this only in Windows.

It acts as an stand-alone application and you can do that just by changing the extension from .html to .hta for your main file.

From Wiki:

> An HTML Application (HTA) is a Microsoft Windows program whose source
>   code consists of HTML, Dynamic HTML, and one or more scripting
>   languages supported by Internet Explorer, such as VBScript or JScript.
>   The HTML is used to generate the user interface, and the scripting
>   language is used for the program logic. An HTA executes without the
>   constraints of the internet browser security model; in fact, it
>   executes as a "fully trusted" application.
>
> The usual file extension of an HTA is .hta.

More Links:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML_Application
http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/reference/article.php/3472841